# Integrate Paypal Here with Openbravo POS

Tags: paypal, openbravo

How can I integrate Paypal Here with Openbravo POS?

The workflow I'm looking for is:

1. Cashier selects card payment on Openbravo POS
2. Bill is automatically transferred to Paypal Here
3. Customer completes payment on Paypal Here
4. Confirmation is automatically transferred to Openbravo POS

I see there is an API for integrating iOS applications with Paypal Here, so this is certainly possible. It would be quite complicated to write an iOS application to do this; perhaps there's a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

I have now implemented my own system to do this. It consists of:

1. OpenBravoPOS scripting and a Java class to upload transaction details and wait for a response
2. A web application that receives the transaction details
3. A mobile web page that uses the [Sideloader API](https://devblog.paypal.com/paypal-here-sideloader-api/) to pass transaction details into Paypal Here
4. A callback on the web app that receives the transaction ID

This is working fine in a real shop. If you're interested in this solution, see [my website](http://www.linkedretail.co.uk/).

Answer (score 1):

To develop a fully-integrated solution, the PayPal Here SDKs for iOS and Android are now available on the PayPal Developer site:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/pph-sdk-overview/

There is also a version for Windows 8.1+ in Beta, available upon request. You can email DL-PayPal-Here-SDK@ebay.com for help with any of these.